# ASMX not returning to JQuery hence the alert is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I tried running the below mentioned code and it shows that the asmx file is returning System.Data.DataSet but the JQuery success function is not alerting.

```
function AuthenticateMember()
{
    var UNam = $('#txtUsername').val();
    var pass = $('#txtPassword').val();
    var Parameter = "{\"Username\":\"" + UNam + "\", \"Password\":\"" + pass + "\"}";
    $.ajax({
        type: "Post",
        url: "HelpNow.asmx/AuthenticateMember",
        data: Parameter,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "Json",
        success: function (data)
        {
            var result = data.d;
            alert(result);
        },
        error: function (requeset, status, error)
        {
            alert(error);
        }
    });
}

[WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public DataSet AuthenticateMember(string Username, string Password)
    {
        DataSet DataStatus;

        DataStatus = _objSM.getMember(Username, Password);

        return DataStatus;
    }
```

[image: in visual studio debugger]

Comment: You shouldn't return an ADO.NET `DataSet` or `DataTable` object directly. Is there a reason you can't use dedicated DTO types?

Comment: What does the actual web-server response body for `AuthenticateMember` look like? Use your browser's F12 tools.

Comment: check your browser network tab and check the request and response